# Confused about XML DOM root node

Tags: xml, dom

According to the following resource:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodetype.asp
```

the node type of DOCUMENT_NODE have the nodeName as "#document" and nodeValue as null. it can have the following node types as its children:

```
Element (max. one), ProcessingInstruction, Comment, DocumentType
```

this gave me a impression that the DOCUMENT_NODE (so-called root node) should be the invisible node above the first visible element node of the document.

But it turned out, given the XML document:

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName returned "bookstore" instead of "#document". Contrary to what was described in the w3schools resource, the "bookstore" element may have more than one "book" elements and it seems inappropriate for the "bookstore" element to have DocumentType node as its child node.

Would anyone please offer some clarification to my confusion?

Comment: document element node is different from document node as xml spec defines document node as the parent of document element node.

Comment: Thanks. That will make sense. Could you please point me to the definition stating the document node as the parent of document element node? How to get the document node with Javascript? The tutorials are a bit confusing as it says x.documentElement returns the root node of the document...

Comment: You need to search the web for DOM spec, it is all in there...